# Update duplicate values instead of inserting on CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

If I want try to insert values with the same primary key, I’m going to receive errors that I can’t insert duplicate values. How do I update those rows instead of trying to insert duplicate data?

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB supports this with both [`UPSERT`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/upsert.html) and [`INSERT...ON CONFLICT`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/insert.html#update-values-on-conflict). However, we recommend using `UPSERT` because of its improved performance.